# ¿Por qué no funciona bien el modal?

Tags: javascript, modal

estoy tratando de pasar la URL de una imagen para mostrarla en el modal. El problema es que se muestra solo una foto y las demas en blanco, chekee la URL si llegaba bien y es correcto.

este es mi **etiqueta a**

```
<span><a href="#" id="btnverfoto" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ver-foto-<?php echo $inc->id_incidencia; ?>" data="<?php echo $inc->foto; ?>"><i class="fa fa-picture-o rounded-circle" aria-hidden="true" style="background: linear-gradient(-90deg, #<?php echo $inc->color_representativo; ?>, #<?php echo $inc->color_representativo; ?>);">
              </i></a></span>
```

este es mi modal:

```
<!--    MODAL FOTO   -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="ver-foto-<?php echo $inc->id_incidencia; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <img id="fotoid" src="" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Volver</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

y éste es mi js:

```
//ver foto
$(document).on('click', '#btnverfoto', function(event) {
      
    var fotourl = $(this).attr('data');
    console.log(base_url + "assets/images/incidencias/" + fotourl);
    $("#fotoid").attr("src",base_url + "assets/images/incidencias/" + fotourl);
});
```

Comment: Los ID deben ser únicos, al estar repetidos, jQuery toma siempre el primero que encuentra y por eso funciona solo para una foto. Cambia `id="btnverfoto"` por `class="btnverfoto"` y la forma de asignar el evento a `$(document).on('click', '.btnverfoto', function(event) {`

Comment: @Triby hice esas modificaciones y tampoco funciona.

Comment: No estan repetidos los ID igual, xq el modal es el mismo, lo que cambie es el atributo src.

Comment: ¿Tienes una modal para cada foto? Eso no es necesario, con una es suficiente. Además, al repetir modales, también se repite el `id="fotoid"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo a la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id):

> El atributo global id define un identificador único (ID) el cual **no debe repetirse en todo el documento**. Su propósito es identificar el elemento al vincularlo (usando un identificador de fragmento), en scripts u hojas de estilo (con CSS).

Entonces, se necesitan algunas correcciones:

- Debes usar una clase en el enlace
- Crea solo una modal con `id="ver-foto"`
- En el enlace cambia el atributo a `data-target="#ver-foto"`
- Para obtener la ruta de la imagen usa `data-src` en lugar de solo `data`, para acceder por [atributos de datos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes); en jQuery usas [$.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

Separo el enlace en varias líneas solo para hacerlo más legible aquí:

```
<span><a href="#" class="btnverfoto" data-toggle="modal"
    data-target="#ver-foto" data-src="<?php echo $inc->foto; ?>"><i class="fa fa-picture-o rounded-circle" aria-hidden="true"
    style="background: linear-gradient(-90deg, #<?php echo $inc->color_representativo; ?>, #<?php echo $inc->color_representativo; ?>);">
    </i></a></span>
```

Creas una sola ventana modal con id simple y, teniendo solo una imagen con `id="fotoid"`, ya se puede mostrar correctamente:

```
<!-- MODAL FOTO -->
<div class="modal fade" id="ver-foto" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <img id="fotoid" src="" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Volver</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Finalmente, en Javascript creas el evento por clase:

```
// Asignar evento por clase
$(document).on('click', '.btnverfoto', function(event) {
    // Obtener URL de imagen desde atributo de datos
    let fotourl = $(this).data('src');
    console.log(base_url + "assets/images/incidencias/" + fotourl);
    $("#fotoid").attr("src",base_url + "assets/images/incidencias/" + fotourl);
});
```